# Arel and ActiveRecord's count throws error

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arel

I'm trying implement a library function which should return `ActiveRecord` relation. Complex SQL query is done with `Arel`. It has to work on multiple database backends so raw SQL queries are the last resort.

Simplified example:

```
Spree::Product < ActiveRecord::Base
end

prod_at = Spree::Product.arel_table

# select record's ids by Arel attribute
> Spree::Product.select(prod_at[:id])
   Spree::Product Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "spree_products"."id" FROM
   "spree_products" WHERE "spree_products"."deleted_at" IS NULL
   => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Spree::Product id: 14>, #<Spree…

# previous call converted to SQL, generates correct query
> Spree::Product.select(prod_at[:id]).to_sql
  SELECT "spree_products"."id" FROM "spree_products" WHERE
  "spree_products"."deleted_at" IS NULL

# Surprisingly, applying ActiveRecord::Calculations.count fails
> Spree::Product.select(prod_at[:id]).count
  ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error
  at or near "Arel"
  LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(#<struct Arel::Attributes::Attribute relation=#...
                              ^
  : SELECT COUNT(#<struct Arel::Attributes::Attribute relation=#<
  Arel::Table:0x00000007553f50 @name="spree_products",
  @engine=Spree::Product(id: integer, …
```

It looks like `.count` methods does not unwind embedded Arel expression to SQL
and passes it as-is.

Even more surprising, other methods from ActiveRecord::Calculations work correctly,
even comparable `.calculate` :

```
> Spree::Product.select(prod_at[:id]).calculate(:count, :id)
  (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT("spree_products"."id") FROM "spree_products" WHERE
  "spree_products"."deleted_at" IS NULL
  => 1253
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong ?
How adjust Arel object to work also with `count` method ? Some workaround ?

I have to return `ActiveRecord_Relation`. The affected count method is called from other 3rd party module which can't be directly modified.

Comment: `Spree::Product.select(prod_at[:id]).size`?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ Unfortunately not an option. As mentioned in the question, I can't change how returned relation object is used.

Answer (score 0):

You could either do:

- `.count(:all)` ([reference](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/15138#issuecomment-48378986))

or

- `.to_a.count` ([reference](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29686#issuecomment-313182388))

The first generates an SQL query through ActiveRecord, and the second converts the query to a Ruby array and counts its size.

Not sure which one is preferred, but I'd assume it's the first since it sticks with Rails' methodology.

Nevertheless, it's worth noting that both return type `Integer`. I'm not sure how to make it return type `ActiveRecord_Relation`, which seems to be something that you're looking for.